# volatility and java

Tags: java, command, computer-forensics, volatility

I'm new to both forensics and java. I just learnt java and I find it quite useful. Recently, I am learning how to integrate commands into the java coding. Is this possible?

I am currently using volatility (CLI) software. I am trying to create a GUI version of it. I have started on some basic research on it and I find it really interesting. However, I do not know how to integrate the commands into java.

Thank you. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Linify

Edit: Here's how the coding is.

```
try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process p = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cd C:/Users/User/Desktop/DumpIt &");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code " +exitVal);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you mean cli commands ??

Comment: yes. volatility is a CLI software. it works in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn external processes in Java using the `System` class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). For example:

```
String command = "cmd /c start volatility.bat";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

With the `Process` object you can access the input / output / error stream of the external command (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: how do I add commands after having it to run change dir?
I tried this:

Comment: Create a batch file to run your whole chain of commands and launch the bat from Java

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752040/alternatives-to-batch-file-since-i-am-unable-to-include-java-code-in-it) <-- maybe you can help me with this question too.